# I am stuck on the verify your account Google on a ZTE TracFone

Tags: stock-android, frp

[image]
It is stuck on the Google login screen

Comment: FRP enabled. Enter the email that was synced with the phone. Should be one of your​ email

Comment: There are thousands of guide on how to bypass FRP

Answer (score 0):

With the phone in that orientation, you'll need to *scroll down* to see the box where you can enter the login details of the Google account you used before resetting the phone.